# Ruby on Rails - Model Hash for Select Tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I really wanted to try to figure out how to use a Category or Type Hashes or Arrays in Models, but I feel like i'm a bit confused.  Here is what I'm trying to do and I would appreciate any help.

I have an Alert Model in my application and I originally had a Alert_Type table but wanted to get rid of it because it was more queries than I needed for really only a high, medium, low type of alert, so I was going to move them into the model

```
  SEVERITY = { "High" => :high, 
               "Medium" => :medium,
               "Low" => :low }

<%= select :alert, :severity, Alert::SEVERITY, {:prompt => "Select one"}  %>
```

I feel like this is incorrect because when I pull the database value it is high, low, medium but need to get the text of that value.  When i did this,

```
SEVERITY = {  :high => "High"
                   :medium => "Medium",
                   :low => "Low"  }
```

I had issues with the dropdowns.  I'm trying to figure out the best practice approach so that when I may or may not need translations, then it would work correctly.  Should I do a hash or just array.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select method needs a array as 3th argument with the next form:

```
[["field for_value_1", "field_for_name_attr_1"],
["field for_value_2", "field_for_name_attr_2"],
["field for_value_n", "field_for_name_attr_n"]]
```

or

```
["field for_value_and_attr_1", "field_for_value_and_attr_2","field_for_value_and_attr_n"]
```

Hashes shouldn't work. To have an array you can make

```
SEVERITY = {  :high => "High"
                   :medium => "Medium",
                   :low => "Low"  }
<%= select :alert, :severity, Alert::SEVERITY.to_A, {:prompt => "Select one"}  %>
```

And pass to the method an array.

FYI, its better the second option (my SEVERITY hash), because (if you know this foget it :) in Ruby, the :one, :two, :three things are instances of the Symbol class.
Symbol class is an special kind of string: every Symbol is Singleton in memory.

This characteristic made it perfect for hash's keys, because always :term == :term ( "Term" != "Term", beacuse there are different instances )

And for values in the hash, its yout election (for your case the best approach is  strings)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I think it makes alot of sense.  I implemented it like this in the code before you responded

Comment: tried this first and had this in the look up in the view Alert::SEVERITY[alert.severity.to_sym]

Comment: I don't undertand you, sorry :(.Do you need to access Alert::SEVERITY from the view? Use cattr_reader or make a class method in the model: def self.severity; Alert::SEVERITY; end  And you can incoke in the view Alert.severity